# Module is imported but its functions can't be called

Tags: python-3.x, module

I have a module that I stored in the site-packages directory as suggested by several sources. I can import other packages installed via pip from that directory. Here is a minimal test case with Python 3.6.3.

THE MODULE MyStuff:

```
def Dummy()
    return(0)
```

TEST PROGRAM:

```
try:
   import MyStuff
except:
   print('Import Failed')    

print(MyStuff)
print(dir(MyStuff))

result = Dummy()
print(result)
```

I ran TEST PROGRAM with the Windows 10 command prompt as administrator with this result.(Blank lines added to improve readability.)

> C:>python K:\PythonProjects\TestDummy.py
>
> \Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\MyStuff.py'>
>
> ['Dummy', '**builtins**', '**cached**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**', >'**name**', '**package**', '**spec**']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "K:\PythonProjects\TestDummy.py", line 9, in module
>
> result = Dummy()
>
> NameError: name 'Dummy' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Dummy` is not defined. However, `MyStuff.Dummy` is.

This is what `dir(MyStuff)` tells you: the name `Dummy` is defined *inside* the `MyStuff` module. If you want this name to be visible in global scope, use `from MyStuff import *`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using Module.function() ?